# Como puedo puedo establecer un valor 0.0 si se ingresa un valor de tipo double como salario en C#

Tags: c#

la idea es que voy a ingresar un salario y si se ingresa un valor negativo el resultado que se establezca en 0.0 ya que la variable es de tipo double, lo he intentado hacer ingresando un valor negativo como lo es -200 pero el resultado me da un cero con entero.

Este es el método que tengo.

```
ublic void comprobarSalarioMensual(){
      if(salarioMensual > 0.0){

         salarioMensual = salarioMensual;
     } else if(salarioMensual <= 0.0){
        
         salarioMensual = 0.0;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que uses 0.0 para representar el cero usando variables tipo double o float ya que 0.0 es igual a 0, si luego quires decimales al imprimir el valor de la variable puedes formatear el valor:

```
double salario = 0;
Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}",salario);
// salida 0.00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lobos.

Comment: Nitpick: No se deberían usar float o double para valores que quieres que sean exactos; después sumas las nóminas de todos los empleados y no te coincide con lo que de verdad pagas cada mes. Si no recuerdo mal (no lo he tocado mucho), .Net tiene un tipo Currency específicamente para eso. Y si no existe un tipo específico, usas un *int* o un *float* y cuentas la unidad básica (céntimos de € en vez de euro, si alguien cobra 109,14€ el valor será 10914) y ya lo ajustas al presentarlo